# Recursive js function to simplify list results

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that will simplify and prune a list of accepted file extentsions

so my first input will look like this

```
"application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/ppt, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"
```

my second will look something like this

```
"pdf", "x-pdf", "vnd.pdf", "pdf", "x-pdf", "ppt"
```

then I want to eventually get to an output like this

```
"pdf", "ppt"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pg886/136/

```
var countdown = function(value, newList, element) {
  if (value > 0) {
    console.log(value);

    newList = includesKey(newList, element)
    console.log("newList", newList);

    return countdown(value - 1, newList, element);
  } else {
    return includesKey(newList, element)
  }
};

//returns a boolean if the new list includes a filter element
function includesKey(newList, element) {
  return newList.filter((a, p, s) =>
    a.includes(element)
  )
}

//prune to a simpler list
function pruneResult(list, filterArray) {
  var container = []; //create holder

  var newList = list.split(",").map((a) => a.split('/')[1]);
  filterArray.forEach(function(element) {


    var li = countdown(2, newList, element);
    console.log("li", li)


    container.push(li);
  })

  //return a flat array - simpler list
  return container.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.concat(curr);
  });
}


var list = "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/ppt, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
var filterArray = ["pdf", "ppt"];

console.log("list1", pruneResult(list, filterArray));


//error handling

var fileType = "image/jpeg";
var wrongTypeMss = "x,y,z";

console.log('File is incorrect type (' + fileType + ') it must be one of the following extensions ' + wrongTypeMss);
```

Comment: Based on what logic? What is preventing you from achieving this?

Comment: There's no need to use recursion, especially since the logic for the 1st and 2nd parts looks to be completely different.  That said, we don't know what logic you're applying so we can't help.  I could give you very simple code to convert the 2nd list into the 3rd, or even the 1st into the 3rd, but I know for a fact your response would be *"but what about when..."*

Comment: @Archer lets see your code sample --- cause the filter array could be extendable or different -- pdf, ppt -- later  jpg, gif, png

Comment: @H.B. - the 2nd run through appears to come out with the same result -- I would want to prune it further to just pdf and ppt --- but even the array input is containing duplicate "pdf"

Comment: "There's no need to use recursion" --- could be right -- how do I go through the other step to remove duplicates --- some regex?  if not x- and if not . prefix?

Comment: a non-recursive -- version -- http://jsfiddle.net/pg886/123/

Comment: something like this -- http://jsfiddle.net/pg886/142/

Comment: -- I've come up with this solution with regex -- http://jsfiddle.net/pg886/157/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
const afterSlash = str => str.substr(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
const unique = (obj, i, arr) => arr.lastIndexOf(obj) === i;

function prune(...valid) {
    return str => str.split(', ')
        .map(afterSlash)
        .filter(unique)
        .filter(obj => valid.includes(obj));
}


const list = "application/pdf, application/x-pdf, application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf, application/ppt, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
const simplify = prune("pdf", "ppt");

const result = simplify(list);
```

Comment: yeah - something like this -- how would I take a prunelist like this  var prune = "pdf, ppt"  -- and push this into the prune function?

Comment: var pruneArray = ["pdf", "ppt"]; var simplify = prune.apply(this, pruneArray);

Comment: @TheOldCounty var pruneArray = ["pdf", "ppt"]; var simplify = prune(...pruneArray);